# Does Unity 4.3 has target version iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, unity-game-engine

I have download Unity 4.3 and try building for ios7 device, but the target version iOS only exists from 4.0 to 6.0
So, does unity 4.3 has target version ios 7?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please do not misuse it.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to build for iOS 6.0 API? It will run on device with iOS 7.0

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not have target versio 7.0 but you can change that in the XCode project settings.